# IDisposable はどのように実装するべきでしょうか？

Tags: c#

IDisposable の実装方法を教えてください

Answer (score 6, accepted):

何らかのリソースを抱えるクラスを実装する場合にIDisposableインターフェースを実装する必要があります。

**リソースを抱えるクラスとは**
単純にIDisposableなオブジェクトをそのクラスのフィールドで保持する可能性があるなら、
それは、何らかのリソースを抱えるクラスということになります。

またIDisposableでなくてもCOMなどWin32APIなどアンマネージな部分がある場合、それらリソースとなります。

**IDisposableの実装方法**

```
class Test : IDisposable {
  private bool disposed = false;

  protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing ) {
     if( !disposed ) {
        disposed = true;

        // ここでフィールドとして保持してあるリソースを解放する。

        if( disposing ) {
           // マネージから呼ばれた場合は、ここを通る
           GC.SuppressFinalize(this);      
        }
     }
  }

  // ファイナライザ
  ~Test() {
     Dispose( false );
  }

  public void Dispose() {
     Dispose( true );
  }
}
```

このように実装し、派生クラスは、Disposeメソッドをオーバーライドするようにします。
その場合、必ず基底クラスのDisposeメソッドを呼び出す必要があります。

**ファイナライザ**

ファイナライザは、Disposeメソッドを呼び出さずにどこからも参照されなくなった場合に
GC(ガベージコレクタ)により、Disposeメソッドを実行するための保険です。
アンマネージリソースを抱える場合などDisposeを呼び出し忘れによる影響がある場合に限り、ファイナライザを定義しておく必要があります。

但し、ファイナライザを定義すると通常のオブジェクトに比べ、長くメモリーに残り続けることになります。
これは、GCの仕様によるものです。

ファイナライザを定義する場合、マネージコードからDisposeメソッドの実行が正常に完了した場合、GC.SuppressFinalize( this )を呼び出し、ファイナライザを呼び出す必要がなくなったことをGCに報告しておく必要があります。

また、ファイナライザは、ファイナライザ専用のスレッドで実行されます。
UI周りをDisposeで触る場合、注意が必要です。

**disposedフラグについて**
Disposeメソッドの再呼び出しに対応するためのフラグです。
Disposeメソッドは、多重呼び出しされるものとして設計すべきでしょう。

複数のスレッドで同時に呼び出される可能性がある場合、Interlockedを使用する方法があります。

```
  private int disposed = 0;

  protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing ) {
     if( Interlocked.CompareExchange( ref disposed , 1 , 0 ) == 0 ) {
        if( disposing ) {
           // TODO: マネージ状態を破棄します (マネージ オブジェクト)。
        }
        // ここでフィールドとして保持してあるリソースを解放する。
     }
  }
```

Comment: MSDNに書かれている実装方法と異なっていますね。PITAさんオリジナルのコードでしょうか？　それとも参考にされた本やサイトがあるのでしょうか？　GC.SuppressFinalize() の位置が違うだけで、MSDNのそれと同じ動作をしていると思うのですが、位置を変えた理由を知りたいです。

Comment: GC.SuppressFinalizeを実行する必要があるかどうかは、ファイナライザ以外のスレッドが正常にDisposeを終えたときです。
つまり、正常にDisposeを完了したため、ファイナライザを実行する必要が無くなったことを報告するものです。

GC.SuppressFinalizeの位置ですが、どちらでも特に問題ありません。

派生クラスでDispose( bool disposing )メソッドをオーバーライドした場合、
基底クラスのDispose( bool disposing )メソッドを呼び出し忘れたり、何らかの理由で実行されなかった場合、ファイナライザで再試行できるようにしています。

Answer (score 6):

別の方法として

親クラスが何でも構わない場合は[Componentクラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx)を継承するのが楽です。Disposeパターンを適切に実装されているので、派生クラスは[Component.Dispose(bool)メソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/d9yzd5cx(v=vs.110).aspx)をオーバーライドするだけで済みます。

Answer (score 4):

インターフェース IDisposable を実装する方法は Dispose パターンとして知られています。
以下のコードを参照してください

```
class FooClass : IDisposable
{
   bool disposed = false;

   public void Dispose()
   { 
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);           
   }

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (disposed)
         return; 

      if (disposing) {
         // マネージリソースの解放
         //...
      }

      // アンマネージリソースの解放
      //...
      disposed = true;
   }

   ~FooClass()
   {
      Dispose(false);
   }
}
```

また、MSDNに、[Disposeメソッドの実装](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/fs2xkftw%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)に詳しく書かれています。