# FileStream はマネージリソースとアンマネージリソースのどちらでしょうか？

Tags: c#

[Disposeパターン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15036/idisposable-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)にてマネージリソースとアンマネージリソースの解放方法に違いがありますが、`FileStream` はどちらとして扱うべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

マネージリソースは .NET のランタイム（CLR）によって管理（マネージ）されているリソースで、その解放処理は**CLRが責任を持ちます**。また、その大半はGCの対象になっています。

一方アンマネージリソースはネイティブAPIで直接確保したリソースなどが該当します。これらの確保・解放にCLRは関与しないため、**利用者が責任を持って**解放する必要があります。

直接・間接的にアンマネージリソースを確保していようが、CLRの管理下にあるオブジェクトはマネージリソースと言えます。故に `FileStream` オブジェクトはマネージリソースです。

---

マネージリソースはいつかは解放されるわけですが、メモリを大量に消費するリソースや、排他的に確保されるリソースなど、自動的な解放を待っていられない場合があります。そのような場合に手動で解放するのが `IDisposable.Dispose()` です。

なのでこれが呼び出された場合には、そのオブジェクトが保持するアンマネージリソースのみならず、メモリを大きく消費するマネージリソースや、 `IDisposable` オブジェクトをすぐに解放する必要があります。これが Dispose パターンの `Dispose(bool)` 内で行うマネージオブジェクトの解放です。

- [Dispose Pattern - MSDN Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)
- [CLRから見たリソースについて - 荒井省三のBlog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20140418052138/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shozoa/archive/2010/09/08/about-resources-on-clr.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

マネージリソースではありますがDispose()すべきです。

次のようなクラスを考えます。

```
class SomeClass {
    private FileStream file;
    ...
}
```

fileの使用を終えたとしてもSomeClassインスタンスから参照されているためこのFileStreamは解放されません。またSomeClass利用者が明示的に解放したくてもアクセスできません。その結果、FileStreamはGCに回収されるまで解放されません。
このような問題があるため、**IDisposableを実装するインスタンスを保持するクラスは同じくIDisposableを実装し、保持しているIDisposableインスタンスをすべて解放すべき**です。

このことはマネージコード分析において [CA1001: 破棄可能なフィールドを所有する型は、破棄可能でなければなりません](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms182172.aspx) 警告の対象となっていることからもわかります。

---

指摘があったので補足します。
Diposableパターンそのままで実装してしまうとデストラクターからDispose()メソッドが呼ばれてしまいますが、SomeClass自身にはアンマネージリソースを保持していないためパフォーマンスの無駄となってしまいます。
しかし、クラス利用者からDispose()可能とする必要があるためIDisposableを実装する点は変わりませんが、Disposableパターンに従わず、Dispose()メソッドだけを実装することになるでしょうか。

Comment: CA1001には「クラスが直接的にアンマネージ リソースを所有していない場合は、ファイナライザーを実装できません。」(it should not implement a finalizer)ともあります。ですのでデストラクター経由の場合は`Dispose()`を呼ぶべきではありません。

Answer (score 4):

アンマネージリソースを保持する`IDisposable`オブジェクトはマネージリソースの範疇に入ります。

Answer (score 2):

FileStreamの内部では、もちろんアンマネージリソースを抱えていますが、閉じ込めていますので
利用者から見れば、マネージリソースになります。

Answer (score -1):

FileStreamなど、アンマネージリソースを使うインスタンスの解放にはusing句を使いましょう。
using句を使うとスコープを抜けるときにDispose()が呼び出されますよ。